# Intermittent Dynamics CRM security error

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, crm

Lately we've been seeing this below error from a web service we use to query Microsoft Dynamics CRM:

> An error occurred while retrieving multiple entities for contact. An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party.

It can be alleviated by restarting the node in IIS, but it will come back after a while.  Once it does, we can reset IIS again, then it works.  This leads me to believe that it's not an issue that can be resolved by syncing the time on the server, although I guess I could be wrong.

If anyone knows what else this might be, please let me know.

Comment: How many front ends hace you got? Maybe one hace the error. Or maybe calling the contact entities launch another thing in a conditional that can't resolve. Check that all the fronts have the same access security requires and the same execution service access. Check too if have a limit to retrieve Big query or similar.

Comment: It would be best to enable tracing and re create the error. Then look at the logs to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Could be your web service authentication token for CRM expires. Is your service caching `IOrganizationService` instances?